# Is it possible to copy a file out of a docker image without actually running the container from that image

Tags: docker

I want to copy some file from a docker image without actually running a container from that image. Is it possible to do so? If yes, what would be steps required ?

Answer (score 23):

There's not a docker cp for images because images are inmutable objects but:

you can create a *non running* container:

```
docker create --name cont1 some-image
docker cp cont1:/some/dir/file.tmp file.tmp
docker rm cont1
```

The full *not accepted* (now rejected) proposal for docker cp on images is here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16079

Comment: Docs for copying file out of a running container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: Or not running, docker cp behaves the same. Just adapt to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner to copy a file from a Docker Image, through a container:

## Image defines CMD

```
docker run --rm \
           -v $(pwd):/binary my-image /bin/sh -c "cp /kube-bench /binary"
```

## Image defines ENTRYPOINT

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint "/bin/sh" \
           -v $(pwd):/binary kube-bench-image -c "cp /kube-bench /binary"
```

Both commands mounts the current directory in order to copy the file `/kube-bench` to it.

Comment: This answer does the same as the selected answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265968/577001 but within a single line. Is there any reason this answer is less favorable?

Comment: @IsaacS if you are automating something, the fewer lines the better (in maintenance costs perspective)

Comment: My question can be rephrased as "Why is this answer not the chosen one" :) ?

Comment: actually the others answers do not trust in a file inside the image. `/bin/sh` can not be present in images `FROM SCRATCH`.  And this one need to run the container. So it's not a response to the question that ask *without actually running the container*.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker image save alpine -o alpine.tar
```

untar, it will have a hash named directory and inside there is a layer.tar which contains the image files.

Comment: to extract all files in a image: `docker image save alpine | tar xvf - | grep layer.tar | xargs -i tar xvf {}`

Answer (score 1):

The Alfonso Tienda response do not work with image without CMD or Entrypoint.

The jhernandez is a good start point to a solution, but it need to extract all files.

What about:

```sh
docker image save $IMAGE |
  tar tf - |
    grep layer.tar |
      while read layer; do
        docker image save $IMAGE | 
          tar -xf - $layer -O |
            tar -xf - $FILENAME ; done
```

So, we can just set the `IMAGE`and `FILENAME` to extract like:

```sh
$ IMAGE=alpine
$ FILENAME=etc/passwd
$ docker image save $IMAGE | tar tf - | grep layer.tar | while read layer; do docker image save $IMAGE | tar -xf - $layer -O | tar -xf - $FILENAME ; done
```

And we can save a some storage space.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I ended up here and none of the existing answers are up to date. Buried in one of the [github threads](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16079#issuecomment-801240270) is this solution:

```
# Build-stage: builds "my-binary" from source
FROM busybox AS buildstage
COPY src src
RUN echo "I built this from src" > /src/build/my-binary

# Stage for --output; must only contain files to ship
FROM scratch AS artifacts
COPY --from=buildstage /src/build/my-binary /
```

Now, with buildkit enabled;

```
$ mkdir shipit
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --output=shipit .

$ ls -la shipit/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 sebastiaan  staff   96 Mar 17 17:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 sebastiaan  staff  160 Mar 17 17:42 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 sebastiaan  staff   22 Mar 17 17:42 my-binary
```