# Is it possible to copy files to an existing docker image without running it?

Tags: python, docker

I want to build a Docker image to run a Python script. I added some files to the image during the building process and installed some python packages.

In the last line of my Dockerfile I have:

```
CMD ["python3", "script.py"]
```

I aim to run this script using the container, but I must provide some input files before running it. Building the image takes some time because I'm adding some large files, so I want to avoid building the image and moving the input files whenever I want to run the script.

Is it possible to do this?

I tried using `docker create` and then copying the files with `cp`, but I don't know how to run the container recently created.

I'm trying to work from this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265968/19257725

Answer (score 0):

[`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) copies files to (and from) containers. And as you shared, you may create a non-running container with [`docker create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/), copy your files with `docker cp` then run the container with:

```
# Example from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#create-and-start-a-container
docker container start --attach -i mycontainer
```

Replace `mycontainer` with your container name.

---

However this may cause Docker to kill your container due to OOM if you have large files, for this I recommend using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), so you would run your container and attach a volume that reads the files from your disk directly, with this you would have a lighter Docker container, and you can ship lighter images, and make data downloadable separately if you want to publish it.

Read more:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514715/5078746
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/